# checkout em projeto svn node/gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, svn

Olá, alguem saberia me dizer como posso fazer checkout de um projeto svn com o node/gulp?

Atualmente eu tenho essa rotina que copia minha pasta do projeto e cria uma nova para que eu possa minificar os arquivos e depois subir para produção. Eu quero altera-la para que ela pegue os arquivos direto do repositório do svn.

```
    gulp.task('copy', ['clean'], function(){
    return gulp.src([projectName + '//**', 
        '!' + projectName + '/app/{config,config/**}', 
        '!' + projectName + '/app/{storage,storage/**}',
        '!' + projectName + '/{nbproject,nbproject/**}',
        '!' + projectName + '/{Scripts,Scripts/**}'
        ])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('version-client'));
});
```

Comment: Sua pergunta nao esta clara Laiane. Tente explicar mais clareza o objeto e colocar trechos relevantes de codigo ou comandos.

Comment: Bem, na verdade eu não tenho nada. Achei algumas bibliotecas em js pra usar mas não tive sucesso com nenhuma. O que eu quero fazer é pegar o meu repositório do svn e fazer o checkout dele em uma pasta na minha maquina utilizando o gulp(mas isso na verdade seria para colocar em produção depois de pronto, assim eu não tenho que ficar copiando pastas para subir em produçaõ quando necessário)

Comment: Hoje eu faço uma rotina que copia os arquivos da minha própria maquina e gera uma pasta da forma que quero pra subir em produção. Sou nova aqui e ainda não sei bem como funciona, não sei se é o certo mas vou colocar como resposta o código que copia a minha pasta local hoje utilizando o gulp